# Routing Audio from microphone to network using QT 6.4.x

Tags: c++, qt6, qtmultimedia

With QT 6.4.x (Windows), how can I capture microphone audio and repackage it and forward the repackaged audio to a QUdpSocket.

The repackaging will involve changing the captured audio format from its typical 16 bit little endian format and converting to 24 bit big endian format where each packet will have a constant size potentially different size payload to that from the microphone. I am not sure but somehow I think I need to replace the QAudioSink with a QAudioDecoder as the description indicates:
***The QAudioDecoder class is a high level class for decoding audio media files. It is similar to the QMediaPlayer class except that audio is provided back through this API rather than routed directly to audio hardware.***

I have a partially working example that contains a mixture of sending synthesized audio directly to the speaker. This functionality is based off the 'Audio Output Example' that ships with Qt 6 (my modified example sends a sine wave generated tone to the speakers).

Also in this RtpWorker thread, using the 'Audio Source Example' for inspiration, I was also able to capture and intercept audio packets from the microphone, but I do not know how to send these packets (repackaged per the above) to a UDP socket in a fixed size datagrams, instead I just log the captured packets.   I think I need an intermediate circular buffer (the write part of which fills it with captured microphone audio while the read part gets called by a [QAudioSink](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qaudiosink.html) or [QAudioDecoder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qaudiodecoder.html) in pull mode).

Per my comment above I think I might need to send them to a QAudioDevice so I can handle the packaging and sending over the network myself.

My code is contained in 2 attachment in the following [QTBUG-108383](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-108383).

It would be great if someone could point to some useful examples that try to do something similar.

Answer (score -1):

try to run Mac OS  or Linux its seems Windows bug

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33874702)